# php foreach duplicate first item

Tags: php, object, foreach, duplicates

For object created from array foreach cycle go through first item twice

```
$list = (object)['a' => 1, 'b' => 2];
echo json_encode($list);

$pointers = [];
foreach($list as $n => $v)
    $pointers[] = &$list->$n;

var_dump($pointers);
```

json returns 2 items, pointers at end returns 3 items. What can be wrong?

But if I create object as stdClass, it works as expected.

```
$list = new stdClass();
$list->a = 1;
$list->b = 2;
echo json_encode($list);

$pointers = [];
foreach($list as $n => $v)
    $pointers[] = &$list->$n;

var_dump($pointers);
```

json returns 2 items, pointers at end returns 2 items

Comment: The pointer array is returning 2 items http://ideone.com/yWDVh3 . Check it out.

Comment: I don't know exactly but this might be related with pointer. If you change to `$list->$n` in your first example you correctly have 2 items. Maybe there is some additional pointer defined when casting to (object). Need to check that out.

Comment: @Ayush In php 7 i have this output `{"a":1,"b":2}array(3) {
  [0]=>
  &int(1)
  [1]=>
  &int(1)
  [2]=>
  &int(2)
}` but it works fine in php 5.6

Comment: 7.1 returns with array(2), seems to be just in 7.0.*

Comment: It's because of the reference call, $list->$n works fine.

Comment: @ConnWarwicker 7.0.* is dumping 3 values. Other versions are working fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears to be an oddity with PHP 7.0, as it works as expected in 7.1 and < 7.

You may have to do something like this instead:

```
$list = (object)['a' => 1, 'b' => 2];
echo json_encode($list);

$pointers = [];
$items = get_object_vars($list);

foreach($items as $key => $val){
    $pointers[] = &$list->$key;
}


var_dump($pointers);
```